# Convert RGB value to HSV

Tags: java, image, rgb, hsv

I've found a method on the Internet to convert RGB values to HSV values.
Unfortunately, when the values are R=G=B, I'm getting a NaN, because of the 0/0 operation.

Do you know if there is an implemented method for this conversion in Java, or what do I have to do when I get the 0/0 division to get the right value of the HSV?

Here comes my method, adapted from some code on the Internet:

```
public static double[] RGBtoHSV(double r, double g, double b){

    double h, s, v;

    double min, max, delta;

    min = Math.min(Math.min(r, g), b);
    max = Math.max(Math.max(r, g), b);

    // V
    v = max;

     delta = max - min;

    // S
     if( max != 0 )
        s = delta / max;
     else {
        s = 0;
        h = -1;
        return new double[]{h,s,v};
     }

    // H
     if( r == max )
        h = ( g - b ) / delta; // between yellow & magenta
     else if( g == max )
        h = 2 + ( b - r ) / delta; // between cyan & yellow
     else
        h = 4 + ( r - g ) / delta; // between magenta & cyan

     h *= 60;    // degrees

    if( h < 0 )
        h += 360;

    return new double[]{h,s,v};
}
```

Comment: For anyone interested in the actual answer to the question, I believe when r=g=b, hsv = [0,0,r/255.0]. The hue is arbitrary, the saturation is 0 (it's a shade of gray) and the value however bright the r=g=b value is.

Answer (score 61, accepted):

I'm pretty sure what you want is [RGBtoHSB](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/awt/Color.html#RGBtoHSB(int,%20int,%20int,%20float[]))

```
int r = ...
int g = ... 
int b = ...
float[] hsv = new float[3];
Color.RGBtoHSB(r,g,b,hsv)
//hsv contains the desired values
```

Comment: what's the difference between HSV and HSB?

Comment: Just a different name for the third value. Hue, Saturation, and Value or Brightness.

Comment: [No, HSB is not the same as HSL!](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HSL_and_HSV) HSB is the same as HSV, because V - value may be called also B - brightness. But HSL gives you simillar idea of color space as HSV, but, just read it from the link.