# Given an RGB value, how do I create a tint (or shade)?

Tags: colors, rgb

Given an RGB value, like `168, 0, 255`, how do I create tints (make it lighter) and shades (make it darker) of the color?

Answer (score 192, accepted):

Among [several options](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1202772/Color-Topics-for-Programmers#Alpha_Blending) for shading and tinting:

- For shades, multiply each component by 1/4, 1/2, 3/4, etc., of its
  previous value. The smaller the factor, the darker the shade.
- For tints, calculate (255 - previous value), multiply that by 1/4,
  1/2, 3/4, etc. (the greater the factor, the lighter the tint), and add that to the previous value (assuming each.component is a 8-bit integer).

Note that color manipulations (such as tints and other shading) should be done in *linear RGB*. However, RGB colors specified in documents or encoded in images and video are not likely to be in linear RGB, in which case a so-called *inverse transfer function* needs to be applied to each of the RGB color's components. This function varies with the RGB color space. For example, in the sRGB color space (which can be assumed if the RGB color space is unknown), this function is *roughly* equivalent to raising each sRGB color component (ranging from 0 through 1) to a power of 2.2. (Note that "linear RGB" is not an RGB color space.)

See also Violet Giraffe's comment about "gamma correction".

Comment: I tried this out and it worked great.  I thought it would be helpful to write examples of the formulas.  Original (r,g,b); Shade (rs,gs,bs): `rs = r * 0.25`, `gs = g * 0.25`, `bs = b * 0.25` (that is a pretty dark shade); Tint (rt,gt,bt): `rt = r + (0.25 * (255 - r))`, `gt = g + (0.25 * (255 - g))`, `bt = b + (0.25 * (255 - b))` (that is a pretty light tint).  I did it as part of a cool array that created lots of hues and it worked great.  Hope that helps.  Thanks Peter.

Comment: You have made a mistake. It is viceversa.

Comment: Are you sure these manipulation must not account for gamma correction?

Comment: @VioletGiraffe: You make a good point with gamma correction. See my edit. (This replaces a deleted comment of mine from 22 hours ago.)

Comment: Thank you: That works great. For example for very bright backgrounds, that perfectly match to the original color I take 0.85 -> NICE

Answer (score 131):

### Some definitions

- A **shade** is produced by "darkening" a hue or "adding black"
- A **tint** is produced by "ligthening" a hue or "adding white"

### Creating a tint or a shade

Depending on your Color Model, there are different methods to create a darker (shaded) or lighter (tinted) color:

- `RGB`:

  - To shade:

    ```
    newR = currentR * (1 - shade_factor)
    newG = currentG * (1 - shade_factor)
    newB = currentB * (1 - shade_factor)
    ```
  - To tint:

    ```
    newR = currentR + (255 - currentR) * tint_factor
    newG = currentG + (255 - currentG) * tint_factor
    newB = currentB + (255 - currentB) * tint_factor
    ```
  - More generally, the color resulting in layering a color `RGB(currentR,currentG,currentB)` with a color `RGBA(aR,aG,aB,alpha)` is:

    ```
    newR = currentR + (aR - currentR) * alpha
    newG = currentG + (aG - currentG) * alpha
    newB = currentB + (aB - currentB) * alpha
    ```

  where `(aR,aG,aB) = black = (0,0,0)` for shading, and `(aR,aG,aB) = white = (255,255,255)` for tinting
- `HSV` or `HSB`:

  - To shade: lower the `Value` / `Brightness` or increase the `Saturation`
  - To tint: lower the `Saturation` or increase the `Value` / `Brightness`
- `HSL`:

  - To shade: lower the `Lightness`
  - To tint: increase the `Lightness`

There exists formulas to convert from one color model to another. As per your initial question, if you are in `RGB` and want to use the `HSV` model to shade for example, you can just convert to `HSV`, do the shading and convert back to `RGB`. Formula to convert are not trivial but can be found on the internet. Depending on your language, it might also be available as a core function :

- [RGB to HSV color in javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8022885/rgb-to-hsv-color-in-javascript)
- [Convert RGB value to HSV](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2399150/convert-rgb-value-to-hsv)

### Comparing the models

- `RGB` has the advantage of being really simple to implement, but:

  - you can only shade or tint your color relatively
  - you have no idea if your color is already tinted or shaded
- `HSV` or `HSB` is kind of complex because you need to play with two parameters to get what you want (`Saturation` & `Value` / `Brightness`)
- `HSL` is the best from my point of view:

  - supported by CSS3 (for webapp)
  - simple and accurate:

    - `50%` means an unaltered Hue
    - `>50%` means the Hue is lighter (tint)
    - `<50%` means the Hue is darker (shade)
  - given a color you can determine if it is already tinted or shaded
  - you can tint or shade a color relatively or absolutely (by just replacing the `Lightness` part)

---

- If you want to learn more about this subject: [Wiki: Colors Model](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Color_Models:_RGB,_HSV,_HSL)
- For more information on what those models are: [Wikipedia: HSL and HSV](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HSL_and_HSV)

Comment: I believe in here _"A shade is produced by "darkening" a hue"_, by hue, you mean the color. Because if you're talking about hue as in HSL/HSV, changing it will produce a different color, not a shade/tint. Hue (0-360°), by itself, can't get darker/lighter. To give a color shade/tint, one would have to modify SL/SV values. This definition might mislead someone into thinking changing the hue will produce a darker/lighter color.

Comment: The shade version only works for colors range starting from 0. Add Half of your color range to the color channel value,then do the math then subtract that range again. If your color is signed and you can do the calculation without destroying something because of overflow this works as intended.

Answer (score 4):

I'm currently experimenting with canvas and pixels... I'm finding this logic works out for me better.

1. Use this to calculate the grey-ness ( luma ? )
2. but with both the existing value and the new 'tint' value
3. calculate the difference ( I found I did not need to multiply )
4. add to offset the 'tint' value

   ```
   var grey =  (r + g + b) / 3;    
   var grey2 = (new_r + new_g + new_b) / 3;

   var dr =  grey - grey2 * 1;    
   var dg =  grey - grey2 * 1    
   var db =  grey - grey2 * 1;  

   tint_r = new_r + dr;    
   tint_g = new_g + dg;   
   tint_b = new_b _ db;
   ```

or something like that...