# Drawing a rectangle with dashed lines using Rafael.js

Tags: javascript, svg, firebug

I am using Rafael.js to draw rectangles on an image.  My problem with setting the stroke color is that the background may be dark or light or any color.  I thought that the best way to deal with that would be using dashed lines.  However this call

```
circle = Canvas.paper.rect(left, topCoord, width, height).attr({stroke-dasharray:"---"});
```

does not work.  Firebug (on FireFox 20.0) returns an error message saying that an existing function in my .js file does not exist.  It appears that stroke-dasharray is not valid for rectangles.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Basic JavaScript error:

```
{stroke-dasharray:"---"}
```

Should be:

```
{"stroke-dasharray":"---"}
```

Also: `"---"` isn't a supported value for `stroke-dasharray`; it should be:

```
{"stroke-dasharray":"--"}
```

Comment: Thanks.  That made the error go away but I am still getting solid black lines for the rectangle.  Thanks, Peter.

Comment: Looking at the [Raphael reference](http://raphaeljs.com/reference.html) I don't think three dashes is a valid option.  Try two: `"--"`

Comment: That worked for getting dashed lines.  Thanks very much!  To get two different colors, I appear to need two calls: one with {"stroke-dasharray":"--"} and one with {"stroke":"white", "stroke-dasharray":"-.."}.  Thanks very much!

Answer (score 9):

No "---", possible stroke-dasharray: `[“”, “-”, “.”, “-.”, “-..”, “. ”, “- ”, “--”, “- .”, “--.”, “--..”]`

One way to color the stroke is to use the HSV or HSL space, then choose the opposite (or nearby) spectrum. Try the answers from: [Given an RGB value, how do I create a tint (or shade)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6615002/given-an-rgb-value-how-do-i-create-a-tint-or-shade?lq=1)

Comment: Interesting.  I think the ideal would be to xor with the underlying image but Rafael does not appear to have that option.  Thanks, Peter.

Comment: Some browser can support <FEimage> manipulation to create a glow around it. Try http://commons.oreilly.com/wiki/index.php/SVG_Essentials/Filters

Answer (score 0):

"stroke-dasharray" values are:

```
"-"     [shortdash]
"."     [shortdot]
"-."    [shortdashdot]
"-.."   [shortdashdotdot]
". "    [dot]
"- "    [dash]
"--"    [longdash]
"- ."   [dashdot]
"--."   [longdashdot]
"--.."  [longdashdotdot]
```