# Xcode can't get colors the same

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I have a progress view and a UIView, setup with these values:

```
healthBar.trackTintColor = UIColor(red: 59/255, green: 153/255, blue: 252/255, alpha: 1.0)
link.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 59/255, green: 153/255, blue: 252/255, alpha: 1.0)
```

However, the trackTint color is not the same as the view. It is slightly darker. Any reason for this?

Comment: It's different because one is a tint and the other is the actual colour. Tint values are typically mixed with a lighter or darker shade depending on the component thats being tinted.

Comment: Is it not possible to assign a color to the progress view instead of a tint?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assigning the same Color (RGB) as a tint does not gives the same output for original color, thats because:

> In color theory, a tint is the mixture of a color with white, which
>   increases lightness, and a shade is the mixture of a color with black,
>   which reduces lightness.

You can find the full Wikipedia resource at [this link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tints_and_shades).

**How Can I solve it?**

However, you CAN generate the appropriate matching for *color* and its *tintColor*, you might want to check [these answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6615002/given-an-rgb-value-how-do-i-create-a-tint-or-shade).

Hope this helped.

Comment: Well, now I know the reason I stoped trying to change the color! I assigned a transparent png to the track and placed a view behind the progress view with the color I wanted and constrained the progress view to it. Thanks.