# Darken or Lighten colors in .NET Core (ControlPaint.Dark equivalent in .NET Core)

Tags: c#, .net-core

In .NET Framework there is `ControlPaint` in the `System.Windows.Forms` namespace for making colors lighter and darker:

```
using System.Drawing;
using System.Windows.Forms;

# .NET Framework Example, make color 100% darker
Colour darkerColor = ControlPaint.Dark(Color.White, 100f);
```

Is there an equivalent native method for this that performs that same function in for .NET Core?

Comment: did you mean to tag this with web tech?

Comment: Down voters, why?

Comment: It's a pretty common thing to want to do in .NET.  There's an entire namespace dedicated to it in .NET Framework.  There doesn't seem to be an answer to this on SO at all, so drive-by down voting isn't really the right thing to be doing.  No I didn't mean to tag it with web tech.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6615002/given-an-rgb-value-how-do-I-create-a-tint-or-shade/) for creating tints or shades of colors. For example, a method for darkening a color (which may not work exactly like `ControlPaint.Dark`) might look like the following:

```
public static Color Darken(Color c, float level){
   // 'level' is how dark to make the color.
   // Each RGB component is divided by 'level'.
   return Color.FromArgb(c.A,
     (int)(c.R/level),(int)(c.G/level),(int)(c.B/level));
}
```

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to answer.  I'm going to give this a go as well as another method that I think will work.