# Convert RGB to HSV in android

Tags: java, android, rgb, hsv

I want to get the ARGB values from a pixel and convert to HSV and then set the pixel with the new values.

I don't fully understand how to do that. Can anyone help me?

Comment: Improved formatting and grammar

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert RGB value to HSV](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2399150/convert-rgb-value-to-hsv)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Let's say you have a Bitmap object and x and y co-ordinates. You can get the color from the bitmap as a 32-bit value like this:

```
int color = bitmap.getPixel(x, y);
```

You can separate out the argb components like this:

```
int a = Color.alpha(color);
int r = Color.red(color);
int g = Color.green(color);
int b = Color.blue(color);
```

Then you can convert to HSV like this:

```
float[] hsv = new float[3];
Color.RGBToHSV(r, g, b, hsv);
```

Now you can manipulate the HSV values however you want. When you are done you can convert back to rgb:

```
color = Color.HSVToRGB(hsv);
```

or like this is you want to use the alpha value:

```
color = Color.HSVToRGB(a, hsv);
```

Then you can write the color back to the bitmap (it has to be a mutable Bitmap):

```
bitmap.setPixel(x, y, color);
```

Comment: But I got this error : "The method alpha(int) is undefined for the type Color" how can I fix this?

Comment: @AlexLing make sure you imported the Color class correctly: import android.graphics.Color;

Comment: @samgak thx for your reply. Yeah I didn't import it correctly cuz I am using pure Java, not android. But do you know how can I do this in pure Java? ( I am not an android developer and I need this in a desktop application) Thanks.

Comment: @AlexLing use the RGBtoHSB function of the Java AWT Color class: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Color.html

Answer (score 4):

Refer to Android documentation: [`public static void Color#RGBToHSV(int, int, int, float[])`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Color.html#RGBToHSV(int,%20int,%20int,%20float[]))

This method converts RGB components to HSV and returns `hsv` - 3 element array which holds the resulting HSV components. `hsv[0]` is Hue [0 .. 360), `hsv[1]` is Saturation [0...1], `hsv[2]` is Value [0...1].

Answer (score 0):

convert RGBA to HSV with OpenCV:

```
import org.opencv.core.CvType;
import org.opencv.core.Mat;
import org.opencv.core.Scalar;
import org.opencv.imgproc.Imgproc;

 private Scalar converScalarRgba2HSV(Scalar rgba) {
    Mat  pointMatHsv= new Mat();
    Mat pointMatRgba = new Mat(1, 1, CvType.CV_8UC3, rgba);
    Imgproc.cvtColor(pointMatRgba,pointMatHsv, Imgproc.COLOR_RGB2HSV_FULL, 4);

    return new Scalar(pointMatHsv.get(0, 0));
}
```

Comment: Could you please specify what are Scalar and Mat? What is Imgproc? And how do you get a Scalar type from a pixel in a Bitmap to pass as argument? Thanks!